# Python request gives 404 response, but I get 200 when I run the code from local server

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-404, python-responses

I have used python requests before. However, now I am facing a 404 problem on this specific site [Jiomart.com](https://www.jiomart.com/).

When I try to sent requests from my local server, it gives me 200 as the response. After when I completed the project and deployed it on the Digital Ocean server, I am getting 404 as the response.
I don't know why. Did anyone experience the same issue?
Instead of [Jiomart.com](https://www.jiomart.com/) all other sites I am getting 200 as response.

My system configuration
Python 3.8.6,
Ubuntu 20.0,
Python Requests

```
site = requests.Session()
res = site.get('https://www.jiomart.com/')
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put that URL through a service that allows you to preview the site from different geographic locations, you'll see that it's georestricted using Amazon Cloudfront's geo blocking feature.